# Upvar downvar swap $i, i-1, i\land i-1$ conventions

Tags: variance-swap

Upvar and downvar swaps are examples of *conditional variance swaps*.

For example a downvar swap only accrues variance for day $i$ (the day whose logarithmic return is $\log S_i/S_{i-1}$) if the underlying $S$ is below a threshold level $H$. This condition can be definded in 3 ways:

1. $S_{i-1} \le H$,
2. $S_{i} \le H$,
3. Both $S_{i-1} \le H$ and $S_{i} \le H$.

Can someone please explain which convention would the investor choose while trading upvar swap and downvar swap among $i$, $i-1$ or  $i \text{ and } i-1$ and correspondingly which spot convention is better for dealers

Comment: The $ i−1$ convention seems the simplest since we know during day $i$  if the previous close was above or below $H$ which makes it easier to hedge.  And I prefer simpler derivatives to more complex ones. But neither convention AFAICS is particularly fair or unfair to either party. To put it more cynically the dealer always has a bit of an edge over the customer; you can't change that.